# javascript restler how to block/wait on a request

Tags: javascript, node.js

https://github.com/danwrong/restler
http://nodejs.org/

in order to download a file, I am using restler from nodejs in a server-side script (not from a client web browser).

I could use the async way to fire an event when the download is completed, as follows:

```
rest = require('./restler');
rest.get('http://google.com').on('complete', function(result) {
  if (result instanceof Error) {
    sys.puts('Error: ' + result.message);
    this.retry(5000); // try again after 5 sec
  } else {
    sys.puts(result);
  }
});
```

but I prefer to use a sync way this time.

**how can I call this and block/wait until I get the response?**

**and how to get the data or error afterwards**

```
var req = rest.get('http://twaud.io/api/v1/users/danwrong.json');
// how to block/wait here until file is downloaded
if (req.response instanceof Error) {  // this does not worn neither
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: There is big reason of having async methods, and you will block the whole process that will involve in idling other requests / responses.
There is always a way of going around it and having use of actual async methods. Please could you describe what reason you want to have a blocking situation, and there might be a good solution for you to stay async with satisfying logical needs of your challenges.

Comment: it is not a script in a client browser. it is a simple script in a server, that runs and finishes when the download is ready. i do not need any async here.

Comment: It will download and trigger "finished" with sync or async, it is not relevant then. So the question "why would you do sync", if async is the same outcome?
Anyway. `restler` does not have `sync` methods or options for methods. You might implement it your self.

Comment: there are advantages and disadvantages of using sync or async, and this is a very interesting discussion. however, it is not the purpose of this question. in this question, i am asking *how* can i block/wait until restler gets the response.

Comment: The answer is: `restler` does not have such functionality. Neither nodejs request libs does not either, as it will mean that node process will have to block even if requested server is not responding. This is generally against the concept of async paradigm.
I will still ask: Why do you need sync request, if you can cover ANY scenario with async requests as well? Solution must be extremely simple if you will explain your needs.

Comment: I've reformulated the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689151/javascript-node-js-in-a-stand-alone-script-block-wait-on-a-promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a library like [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step), which will make restler appear synchronous.

You provide it a series of functions, so that you can write your code in a more linear fashion.

```
var rest = require('restler');
var Step = require('step');
var sys = require('sys');

function retry(millis) {
    console.log('Queing another try');
    setTimeout(download, millis);
}

function download() {
    Step(function() {
            // 1
            console.log('Starting download');
            rest.get('http://google.com').on('complete', this);
        },
        function(result) {
            // 2
            console.log('Download complete');
            if (result instanceof Error) {
                sys.puts('Error: ' + result.message);
                retry(5000); // try again after 5 sec
            } else {
                sys.puts(result);
            }
            return result;
        },
        function(result) {
            // 3
            console.log("This won't run until after Download is complete");
        });
}
download();
```