# javascript node.js in a stand-alone script, block/wait on a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I have a simple program in node.js, such as:

```
// CODE1
step1();
step2();
var o = step3();
step4(o);
step5();
step6();
```

this program is meant to be run in a stand-alone script (not in a web browser),
and it is a sequential program where order of execution is important (eg, step6 needs to be executed after step5).

the problem is that step3() is an async function, and the value 'o' is actually passed to a given callback,
so I would need to modify the program as follows:

```
// CODE2
step1();
step2();
step3( function (o) {
  step4(o);
  step5();
  step6();
})
```

it could make sense to call step4 from the callback function, because it depends on the 'o' value computed by step3.
But step5 and step6 functions do not depend on 'o', and I have to include them in that callback function only to preserve the order of execution: step3, then step4, then step5 then step6.

this sounds really bad to me.
this is a sequential program, and so I would like to convert step3 to a sync function.

how to do this?
I am looking for something like this (eg using Q):

```
// CODE3
step1();
step2();
var deferred = Q.defer();
step3(deferred.resolve);
deferred.blockUntilFulfilled()     // this function does not exist; this is what i am looking for
var o = deferred.inspect().value
step4(o);
step5();
step6();
```

How to do this?

ps: there are advantages and disadvantages of using sync or async, and this is a very interesting discussion. however, it is not the purpose of this question. in this question, i am asking how can i block/wait until a promise (or equivalent) gets fulfilled. Please, please, please, do not start a discussion on whether sync/blocking is good or not.

Comment: "have to include them in that callback function only to preserve the order of execution": yeah, but that's precisely the point of callbacks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to turn an async operation into a sync operation in vanilla JavaScript. There are things like node-fibers (a C++ add-on) that will allow this, or various compile-to-JS languages that will make the async operations look sync (essentially by rewriting your first code block to the second), but it is not possible to block until an async operation completes.

One way to see this is to note that the JavaScript event loop is always "run to completion," meaning that if you have a series of statements, they will always be guaranteed to execute one after the other, with nothing in between. Thus there is no way for an outside piece of information to come in and tell the code to stop blocking. Say you tried to make it work like so:

```
stepA();
stepB();
while (global.operationIsStillGoing) {
  // do nothing
}
stepC();
```

This will never work, because due to the run-to-completion nature of JavaScript, it is not possible for anything to update `global.operationIsStillGoing` during the `while` loop, since that series of statements has not yet run to completion.

Of course, if someone writes a C++ addon that modifies the language, they can get around this. But that's not really JavaScript any more, at least in the commonly understood sense of ECMAScript + the event loop architecture.

Comment: @dandavis would love to see some demo code. I believe the run-to-completion semantics of the event loop prevent this from ever happening.

Comment: it's not magic, the trick is as you describe. you can use eval/Function to make new sub-routines, or use throw to create a continuation-type internal callbacks. i've played with both. you're right that it's not actually stopping anything, which would be bad, it's re-arranging code around... i found an old working jsonp sat-afternoon proof of concept i did exactly to try to "turn an async operation into a sync operation in vanilla JavaScript". if i'd spent more than a sitting on it, i'd want an AST and all that, but this was fun: http://danml.com/pub/sentry.html

Comment: I am not talking about vanilla JavaScript. I am talking about nodejs. I can run a simple setTimeout function that could update global.operationIsStillGoing.

Comment: @DavidPortabella that's not true; it is impossible for `setTimeout`, which just queues a timer into the event loop, to interrupt the run-to-completion series of statements. If the `while` loop never yields to the event loop, the queued timer will never trigger. I suggest you try it in your local Node.js installation.

Comment: @dandavis right, so you've created your own compile-to-JS language inside of JS at runtime ^_^

Comment: @Domenic, I've tried that, and yes, you are right; I got the point, thanks.

Comment: so, what would do you for my example? do you think that CODE2 is the way to go? do you like it, or you also find it ugly? any other idea? maybe using Q.then(step1).then(step2)...then(step6).done() (or equivalent [step1, step2..., step6].reduce(Q.when, Q()).done())?

Comment: I think CODE2 is more or less the best you can do in JavaScript. I don't think the Q versions are great because you're not clearly separating your sync and async functions, but that's a matter of opinion. In the next version of JavaScript we'll be able to use generators to make it much prettier though, see http://jlongster.com/A-Study-on-Solving-Callbacks-with-JavaScript-Generators